# How can I add days to a certain date and skip Sunday and continue on other days?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I'm trying to create an array of dates. The idea is that I add a number x days and the code, when adding the days skip only Sunday.

This is for laravel and I'm using carbon.

```
$date = Carbon::now();
   $dates = [];

   for($i = 1 ; $i < 20; $i++){


    if($date->dayOfWeek === Carbon::SATURDAY){

        echo $dates[$i] = $date->addDay(1)->format('d/m/Y') . " - Sunday <br> ";


    } else {


        echo $dates[$i] = $date->addDay(1)->format('d/m/Y') . "<br>";

    }
```

When i use the constant SUNDAY to skip this date, its not working. 
It goes on to consider Sunday as Monday

Comment: what is the exact question ? you want to enhance the code ?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you have a type in the else statement. you have the variable ```$data``` which does not exist.

Comment: This code is not working as I expected. It always returns a day later, when I place the constant sunday.

I read the documentation and did not figure out how to implement this. I would like help with the code. Thank you

Comment: @paulrodrigues my mistake when i copy  the code

Comment: I might have an idea what's going on. Could you include the results in your question? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I got it. Just use that code.

Comment: $inicialDate = Carbon::now();
  $newDate = [];

  for($i = 1; $i < 30; $i++)
  {

   $newDate[$i] = $inicialDate->addDay(1);

    if($newDate[$i]->format('l') == "Sunday") 
    {
     $newDate[$i] = $inicialDate->addDay(1);
    }

    echo $newDate[$i]->format('d/m/Y') . " - " . $newDate[$i]->format('l') . "<br>";

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking if it's Saturday, and **after that** you're adding a day to it.
You need to echo the date **before** you add a day to it.

Try this:

```php
if($date->dayOfWeek === Carbon::SUNDAY){ // checking if the current date is a sunday
    echo $dates[$i] = $date->format('d/m/Y') . " - Sunday <br> "; // echo and add the current date to the array
    $date->addDay(1);
} else {
    echo $dates[$i] = $date->format('d/m/Y') . "<br>"; // echo and add the current date to the array
    $date->addDay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this code:

```
$inicialDate = Carbon::now();
    $newDate = [];

    for($i = 1; $i < 30; $i++)
    {

        $newDate[$i] = $inicialDate->addDay(1);

            if($newDate[$i]->format('l') == "Sunday") 
            {
                $newDate[$i] = $inicialDate->addDay(1);
            }

            echo $newDate[$i]->format('d/m/Y') . " - " . $newDate[$i]->format('l') . "<br>";

    }
```